# Intersection of an orbit and its translation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group acting transitively on the space $X$. Let $x\in X$ and write
$X=G\cdot x=G/H$.

Let $A$ be a subgroup of $G$ and consider the orbit $Y:=A\cdot x$. Suppose that $g\cdot Y\cap Y\not=\varnothing$ for some $g\in G$. Is it necessary that $g\cdot Y=Y$?

> My attempt: Suppose that $ga_1\cdot x=a_2\cdot x$ for some $a_1,a_2\in A$ then 
>   $a_2^{-1}ga_1\in H$ so $g=a_2ha_1^{-1}$. Now for any $a\in A$ we have $ga\cdot x = a_2ha_1^{-1}\cdot x=a_2h\cdot x_1$ for some $x_1\in Y$. the question becomes now is $h\cdot x_1\in Y$?

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @Shaun I added an attempt to the question and cleared where is my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no.

Here's an intuitive counterexample. Suppose $G$ is the group of rigid motions of the plane $X=\mathbb{R}^2$, in which case the stabilizer of (say) the origin is the rotation group $H=\mathrm{SO}(2)$. Let $A\cong\mathbb{R}$ be the set of translations along some line, so $Y$ is any parallel line. Then if $g\in G$ is a rotation (not $0^{\circ}$ or $180^{\circ}$), the line $gY$ intersects the line $Y$, but they are not parallel hence not the same line.

The smallest counterexample will occur with $G=S_3$ acting on $X=\{1,2,3\}$. Since it is so small I will let you try your hand at finding $A$ and $Y$ and $g$.